# Page.Ispostback now always returns false

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

For some unknown reason a fully functioning web page now started working incorrectly from what seems to be a problem with postback.

This has been working for ages but recently stopped working, possibly because the solution was upgraded from VS2012 to VS2015 but I'm not sure...

It's easy, I have a asp:button runat=server that I click programmatically with jquery. The button has a corresponding serverside onclick-method that it's supposed to execute onclick.

I noticed that it never enters the method when clicked and some debugging shows me that when I enter page_load the IsPostback always returns false even though the button was clicked..

If I put a breakpoint in page_init I can see that IsPostback returns true but when it gets to page_load it returns false and consequently never enters the metod and other serverside controls have lost their viewstate value and are all "reset" so to speak.

What can be the cause of this??

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies behind your statement, "I have a asp:button runat=server that I click programmatically with jquery." I suspect that when you look at how you are doing this you are changing something about the request going to the server.

Watch the traffic. See that the request is actually a POST. Then make sure that the form input value for the button is correct.

Comment: No luck so far, I have tried adding a new asp:button and created a corresponding serverside method but the behaviour is the same regarding to isPostback being true in pageinit but false in pageload.

Comment: I think you are looking at two separate requests.  Make sure there isn't another request happening between your breakpoints landing.

Answer (score 0):

I sort of found the cause of the problem. I completely dissected the page piece by piece until the error disappeared (hours of work). The error is caused by this line of code in the html page within the head-tag:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="0" src="javascript:false;" />
```

There are no references to this iframe when the page loads, only by jquery when a user clicks a row in a list (html-table). How this can cause the problem is a complete mystery to me. Bare in mind that this code is identical to the code that is installed on our internal test servers and the production environment. It is only on my computer this doesnt work and for no other reason that I can think of besides that I noticed it after I upgraded the solution file from 2012 to 2015...